# Get path helpers from controller name

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the Routes documentation. I read that we can get paths like this:

```
  iex> import HelloWeb.Router.Helpers
  iex> alias HelloWeb.Endpoint
  iex> user_path(Endpoint, :index)
       "/users"
```

Is there any way we can get can `user_path` from controller `User` like this

```
   user_path
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not public API and may change in the future, but `MyApp.Router.__routes__/0` can be used to fetch all the routes. From that you can filter by the controller and get all routes that point to that controller.

I have a standard `resources "/posts", PostController` in my application. Here's some `iex -S mix` output from that application:

```
iex(1)> MyApp.Router.__routes__ |> hd
%Phoenix.Router.Route{
  assigns: %{},
  helper: "page",
  host: nil,
  kind: :match,
  opts: :index,
  path: "/",
  pipe_through: [:browser],
  plug: MyApp.PageController,
  private: %{},
  verb: :get
}
iex(2)> for route <- MyApp.Router.__routes__,
...(2)>     route.plug == MyApp.PostController,
...(2)>   do: route.helper
["post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", nil, "post"]
```

Comment: Thanks this helps.